# Nokogiri: how to parse text fragment?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have such example:

```
html= <<EOT
<div>Some text1
  <p>Some text2</p>
</div>
EOT
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
puts doc.css('div').text
```

This makes:

```
Some text1
  Some text2
```

But i need "Some text1" only

Answer (score 2):

```
doc.css('div').children.first.text
# => "Some text1\n  "

doc.css('div').children.first.text.rstrip
# => "Some text1"
```

Answer (score 1):

One XPath expression and a `strip` will get you there:

```
some_text1 = doc.xpath('//div/text()[1]').text.strip
```